# C code version indication

Tags: c, versioning

I have 2 compiler options that enable/disable specific methods in my code, and when I build my code, I'm building both of the versions as `.LIB` files. But their output looks the same when I look at both of the builds. I'm not using an hex editor to compare the binary data BTW.

The code looks like this:

```
#define TEST_BUILD
//#define REL_BUILD

#ifdef TEST_BUILD
#define ENABLE_METHOD1
#define ENABLE_METHOD2
#endif

#ifdef REL_BUILD
#define ENABLE_METHOD3
#define ENABLE_METHOD4
#endif
```

The question is, how can I make an indicator which file indicates which version of the build? Is there any common way to do this?

I've thought a way like this:

```
#ifdef TEST_BUILD
char *caCodeVersion = "V01.01.16T";
#endif
#ifdef REL_BUILD
char *caCodeVersion = "V01.01.16R";
#endif
```

And when I look into the binary output, I'll see this string inside the code and know which version and build it contains. Is there any other way to do something like this?

BTW, the output files need to be the same name.

Comment: In C that's about the only way to do it.

Comment: I've tested it and realised that C compiler discards unused defines :) That didn't work either.

Comment: The `caCodeVersion`s didn't get included in the libraries? Exactly where did you put them?

Comment: Sorry, I was using another defines instead of char ptr's. Now I converted them to const char ptr's. I'll write the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I've had success in one of my trials, so this is one of the answers.

The defines would be:

```
#ifdef TEST_BUILD
char *caCodeVersion = "V01.01.16T";
#endif
#ifdef REL_BUILD
char *caCodeVersion = "V01.01.16R";
#endif
```

And the key part, you need to use this variable in your code to keep it away from the compiler optimization.

Simply I've used it in one of my functions that memset's zero to a char array.

```
strcpy(caBuffer, caCodeVersion);
memset(caBuffer, 0x00, sizeof(caBuffer));
```

So it the compiler kept the `caCodeVersion`variable inside the output binary.

If I open the output binary with a text editor and find "V01.01.16T", it's a test version of the code. Otherwise it's a release version.

Comment: this is the simplest way to differentiate the versions

Comment: Depending on how you program is being run, you might want to build a piece of code that *prints* the version - If you build a library, define a method to print, in case you build an application, you could have a command line option printing the version.

Comment: My program runs on a device and without loading the program to the device, I needed to find out what the compile version it contains. The device shows what the version it is.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest this method :

```
#ifdef TEST_BUILD
    func_vers_V01.01.16T(void )
    {
         //Dummy package
    }
#endif

#ifdef REL_BUILD
    func_vers_V01.01.16R(void )
    {
         //Dummy package
    }
#endif
```

Now you can use nm command or other related commands to read symbols in binary file.

If func_vers_V01.01.16T symbol exists than it is Test Build else Rel build.

Hope this will help.

Comment: This is a good way to catch the difference but if you are on a linux/dev machine. Right?

Comment: Win with an ARM compiler.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> char *caCodeVersion = "V01.01.16R";
> ```

That's a common way to do that. Another possibility is to use the `#ident` pragma present in many compilers:

```
#ident "v01.01.16R"
```

However, this pragma isn't standard. Make sure your compiler supports it!

To make the original `char*` approach work more reliably, put the constant into a source file that defines other (used) things as well so the object file is not discarded.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at that.